# URL redirect with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, http, url, jira

I've installed JIRA and configured it to operate on port 8090.  In order to get to it I go to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8090
```

What I want to do is to make it accessible through this URL:

```
http://localhost/jira/
```

Is there a way through apache or tomcat to make this happen?

I'm running Apache2, Tomcat6 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use mod_proxy on apache, try doing this in the default vhost:

ProxyPass /jira/ http://localhost:8090
ProxyPassReverse /jira/ http://localhost:8090

this should always keep your url to http://localhost/jira meanwhile in the background it proxies to the port on 8090

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It looks like I misunderstood the OP's question.

If Apache is listening on :80, and you would like the /jira path to proxy transparently back to your tomcat instance listening on :8090, then the mod_proxy solution provided by coderwhiz is the most straight-forward way of doing so.

mod_proxy should be included in the apache2.2-bin package, so it should already be installed.

Comment: Mr Tuttle, I think he (or she) was asking how to configure apache or tomcat to listen on port 80 and redirect to jira. If you could fix your answer, I wont ding you for this one.